# Auto focus in cwac-camera not working

Tags: android-camera, commonsware-cwac, autofocus

I'm using the cwac-camera demo app and the auto focus is not working.

when I'm trying to take a picture, I don't see that the camera focuses.

I checked the logs and I don't see any warning/error.

I tried it on my Nexus 4 and on LG G2.

Thank you!

Comment: As noted on [the project home page](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), you should be moving to some other library.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm trying to migrate to your new library cwac-cam2, sorry if it is a little Off-Topic, but is there any equivalent method for "saveImage" so I can save my image the way I want, instead to a specific file?

Comment: No, because you are invoking an activity, one that is designed to mimic `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Like the original CWAC-Camera library, CWAC-Cam2 is designed for very simple scenarios. Unlike the original CWAC-Camera library, I am enforcing the design this time.

Comment: I see. Do you have any suggestion for me if I want to control the way I save my images/videos? :)

Comment: @CommonsWare Forgot to tag

Comment: Find a library not written by me. :-) I do not have any specific recommendations, though I seem to recall another couple of libraries popping up on the Android Arsenal in recent months.